# How do I collapse variables within the same row using BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Say I have the following using BigQuery:

```
WITH GradeIN AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Student, NULL AS Grade1, 'A+' AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, 'C' AS Grade4, 'A' AS Grade5
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS Student, 'C' AS Grade1, 'A' AS Grade2, 'B' AS Grade3, 'B' AS Grade4, 'A' AS Grade5
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS Student, 'F' AS Grade1, 'F' AS Grade2, 'A' AS Grade3, 'B' AS Grade4, 'C' AS Grade5
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS Student, NULL AS Grade1, NULL AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, NULL AS Grade4, 'C' AS Grade5
   UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS Student, 'A' AS Grade1, 'A' AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, NULL AS Grade4, NULL AS Grade5
)
SELECT * FROM GradeIN
```

I would like to collapse Grades, removing the nulls and *sliding them over* until I have 3 down to have something like the following:

```
Student | New_Grade1 | New_Grade2 | New_Grade3
   1    |    A+      |    C       |     A
   2    |    C       |    A       |     B
   3    |    F       |    F       |     A
   4    |    C       |   null     |    null
   5    |    A       |    A       |    null
```

Keep in mind there can be infinite grades such as ABA, FOP, EEEEE, etc, the data is obviously mocked up.

Comment: lets say stundet 1 has A+ A  E C you would only want A+ A C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery, to get the result you want:

1. You can first construct array from all columns.
2. And then filter null values using [ARRAY(SELECT FROM UNNEST() WHERE)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays) syntax.
3. At the end, use [SAFE_ORDINAL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#accessing_array_elements) to access the reduced array in the end.

Here is the query:

```
WITH GradeIN AS (
      SELECT 1 AS Student, NULL AS Grade1, 'A+' AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, 'C' AS Grade4, 'A' AS Grade5
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 AS Student, 'C' AS Grade1, 'A' AS Grade2, 'B' AS Grade3, 'B' AS Grade4, 'A' AS Grade5
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 AS Student, 'F' AS Grade1, 'F' AS Grade2, 'A' AS Grade3, 'B' AS Grade4, 'C' AS Grade5
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 AS Student, NULL AS Grade1, NULL AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, NULL AS Grade4, 'C' AS Grade5
       UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 AS Student, 'A' AS Grade1, 'A' AS Grade2, NULL AS Grade3, NULL AS Grade4, NULL AS Grade5
    ),
GradeIn_without_null AS (
SELECT
    Student, ARRAY(SELECT X FROM UNNEST([Grade1,Grade2,Grade3,Grade4,Grade5]) AS X WHERE X IS NOT NULL) as not_null_grades
FROM
    GradeIN
)
SELECT
    Student,
    not_null_grades[SAFE_ORDINAL(1)] AS New_Grade1,
    not_null_grades[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] AS New_Grade2,
    not_null_grades[SAFE_ORDINAL(3)] AS New_Grade3
FROM
    GradeIn_without_null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider below

```sql
SELECT Student,
       grades[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS New_Grade1,
       grades[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS New_Grade2,
       grades[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS New_Grade3,
  FROM (
    SELECT Student, ARRAY_AGG(grade) grades
      FROM GradeIN t, UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', t), '()'), ', ')) grade WITH offset
     WHERE offset > 0 AND grade <> 'NULL' -- for removing *Student* field AND *NULL*
     GROUP BY 1
  );
```

[image]